# "Can't connect to X11 window" exception while running ./config.sh

Tags: weblogic12c

I am getting below exception, while running ./config.sh to configure weblogic12c (12.2.1) domain.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '10.202.60.139:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
        at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:126)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
        at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getSystemMnemonicKeyMask(SwingUtilities2.java:2020)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel.initComponentDefaults(BasicLookAndFeel.java:1158)
        at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.initComponentDefaults(MetalLookAndFeel.java:431)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel.getDefaults(BasicLookAndFeel.java:148)
        at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.getDefaults(MetalLookAndFeel.java:1577)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:539)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:579)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.initializeDefaultLAF(UIManager.java:1349)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.initialize(UIManager.java:1459)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.maybeInitialize(UIManager.java:1426)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults(UIManager.java:659)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.put(UIManager.java:988)
        at com.oracle.cie.common.ui.gui.GUIHelper.initPLAF(GUIHelper.java:56)
        at com.oracle.cie.wizard.internal.cont.GUIContext.<clinit>(GUIContext.java:328)
        at com.oracle.cie.wizard.internal.cont.GUITaskContainer.createTaskContext(GUITaskContainer.java:107)
        at com.oracle.cie.wizard.internal.cont.GUITaskContainer.createTaskContext(GUITaskContainer.java:24)
        at com.oracle.cie.wizard.internal.cont.AbstractTaskContainer.init(AbstractTaskContainer.java:34)
        at com.oracle.cie.wizard.internal.cont.GUITaskContainer.init(GUITaskContainer.java:24)
        at com.oracle.cie.wizard.internal.engine.EmbeddedEngine.loadTaskContainer(EmbeddedEngine.java:459)
        at com.oracle.cie.wizard.internal.engine.EmbeddedEngine.configureMode(EmbeddedEngine.java:398)
        at com.oracle.cie.wizard.internal.engine.EmbeddedEngine.init(EmbeddedEngine.java:104)
        at com.oracle.cie.wizard.internal.engine.WizardControllerEngine.init(WizardControllerEngine.java:58)
        at com.oracle.cie.wizard.WizardController.createWizardEngine(WizardController.java:129)
        at com.oracle.cie.wizard.WizardController.<init>(WizardController.java:30)
        at com.oracle.cie.wizard.WizardController.invokeWizardAndWait(WizardController.java:138)
        at com.oracle.cie.wizard.WizardController.main(WizardController.java:69)
```

Answer (score 0):

The config.sh script launches a java-based UI. You need to have an X server running on your server. If you have an X server available then you may need to set the DISPLAY variable in the terminal you are running config.sh from.